# EmberJS condition from helper not working

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have helper istrue.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function() {
  return true;
});
```

In my template i use:

```
{{#if istrue}}
    true
{{else}}
    false
{{/if}}
```

So, in browser window i always get "false".

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isTrue` refers to the property related to the template (in this case it could be controller's property or component's property.

Since your `isTrue` is undefined, the `{{if}}` helpers evaluates the *false* branch.

I guess what you want to achieve is following:

```
{{istrue}}
```

or

```
{{istrue param}}
```

In the second case add the parameter to your helper function:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function(param) {
  return true;
});
```

Also combination should be possible afterwards:

```
{{#if (istrue param)}}
```

More details could be found at: [Ember Guides - Writing own helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/templates/writing-helpers/)

Comment: Yeah, this is it!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Please use ember helper in this way. paste following code in your istrue.js helper file.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function istrue(/*, hash*/) {

    return true;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(istrue);
```

than install following addon

```
ember install ember-truth-helpers
```

this addon will give you truth condition in ember templates

Now you can use following code in you template file to get result

```
{{#if (eq (istrue) true)}}
    true
{{else}}
    false
{{/if}}
```

it will return true, because helper return true.

https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers